# UITextView Alignment Problem

Tags: iphone

I have an UITextView with many lines of text but there is no option for the text Alignment
Justified? So how to Justified the text so it look proper.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to use a `UIWebView` with some formatted HTML—UITextView's styling options are pretty limited.

Answer (score 0):

Its crazy but there is no simple solution, you have to measure your text height and set the origin y of your UITextView, there are a lot of such codes on Internet.